# Add Custom String Labels to Excel Scatterplot with Python xlswriter

Tags: python, excel, charts

I have been trying to use xlswriter to outsheet a scatterplot with custom data labels. It looks like I am implementing the following code exactly how the documentation shows, but somehow I only see the numerical Y-axis value labels and my custom labels do not show up.

My code:

```
chart1 = wb.add_chart({'type': 'scatter'})
custom_labels=[{'value':c} for c in currency_list]
chart1.add_series({'name':'=FX!$B$1', 'categories': '=FX!$B$2:$B$22', 'values':'=FX!$H$2:$H$22','data_labels': {'value': True, 'custom': custom_labels}})
chart1.set_style(11)
ws0.insert_chart('B1', chart1)
```

To me, this is the exact code as recommended in the docs, except they are doing it for a line graph and I am doing it for a scatterplot:

Code example on https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html

```
custom_labels = [
    {'value': 'Jan'},
    {'value': 'Feb'},
    {'value': 'Mar'},
    {'value': 'Apr'},
    {'value': 'May'},
    {'value': 'Jun'},
]

chart.add_series({
    'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$6',
    'data_labels': {'value': True, 'custom': custom_labels},
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized this was not working because my xlsxwriter was out of date. Once I upgraded to 1.3.3 from 1.0.2, I got this code to work!